# Amalgamate two merges in Git

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-rebase

I have a Git branch which is a `topic` branch that shows the project `master`. I merged it with the master and resolved a conflict manually. After that, a critical bug was fixed in `master` and I merged again, this time without conflict. I did not commit anything myself between the two merges and I have not pushed the branch to anyone else. I would like to combine the two merges.

What I have now is:

```
master ----A---B-----C---------->
                \     \
topic   ---W-----X-----Y-------->
```

Where:

- X is the merge where a conflict was fixed
- C is the critical bug fix on master
- Y is the merge incorporating this fix

I would like to make this into:

```
master  ----A---B---C----------->
                     \
topic   ----W---------X'-------->
```

Where X' is now a merge incorporating the conflict resolution and the bugfix in a single merge commit.

I know I could do it manually by checking out W and merging `master`, and copying the contents of the resolved files from X during the inevitable conflict. Is there a quicker way with less chance of messing it up (in the case that the conflict was large and ugly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly haven't pushed anything since at least `W`, then this is probably the easiest way (outside of the actual conflict resolution - which may be painful, I guess) to accomplish it:

```
git checkout topic
git reset --hard W
git merge master
```

If you have pushed since `W`, though (in particular if either `X` or `Y` exist anywhere outside your repository), I'm not sure there is a clean solution to this - no matter what you do, you'll cause problems for any other repositories that have either `X` or `Y` in them.

Of course, you'll have to re-do the conflict resolution, unless you have `rerere` enabled.

Comment: With `rerere`, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Quicker?

```
git checkout topic
git rebase -i W
```

You can then squash the last two commits.

```
git merge -ours master
```

(to record again the merge between `master` and `topic`, without having to "redo" the merge)

You could also try with the `-p` (`--preserve-merge`) option, to preserve those merge links between master and topic

```
git rebase -p -i W
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you could just do `git rebase origin/master` here..

Another point is that branches are cheap. Why not create a seperate clone of your `topic` say `topic'` and then manipulate him, at the end you can do a diff between it and `topic` to show yourself that you haven't changed anything (only commit history has changed)

Comment: Yes, this is one way to do it, but then you have to manually re-do all the conflict resolution.